# change style using ngModelChange

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I was wondering if it was possible to style an element using ngModelChange. I tried the following but that doesn't work

```
<input class="input" [(ngModel)]="counter" (ngModelChange)="$event > 2 ? [style.border-color]='#ff4d4d' : [style.border-color]='#dbdbdb'" type="number">
```

I know that I could do something like

```
<input class="input" [(ngModel)]="counter" (ngModelChange)="$event > 2 ? error=true : error=false" type="number" [style.border-color]="error ? '#ff4d4d' : '#dbdbdb'">
```

But I want to remove if possible the 'error' attribute and assign directly the style to the input depending of the condition

Comment: You can not do like your first statement & what is the problem if the logic is working in the second statement? Or achieve the same thing by creating a function in `.ts`

Comment: There is no problem with the second statement, my goal was 'to remove if possible the 'error' attribute', I was cleaning my code and I was wondering if I could change style directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of handling `ngModelChange`, you could use normal style binding with the condition on `counter`, which has the same value as the `$event` parameter of `ngModelChange`:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="counter" [style.border-color]="counter > 2 ? '#ff4d4d' : '#dbdbdb'" class="input" type="number">
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eg41xj) for a demo.

Comment: can this be done if (ngModel) is a list of object and you want to do the conditional by checking a property within an object?
eg - counter is ```counter = [ {name: 'x'} , {name: 'y'} ]```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that will be possible as we can't do property binding [style] inside an event binding (ngModelChange) as one is happening at the view and another at Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your code by adding function based approach.

**HTML**

```
<input class="input" [(ngModel)]="counter" (ngModelChange)="changeColor($event)" type="number" [style.border-color]="color"  type="number">
```

**.TS**

```
color="dbdbdb";
  changeColor(event) {
    if(event > 2){
      this.color = "#ff4d4d";
    }else{
      this.color = "#dbdbdb";
    }
  }
```